# Can I implement `v-model` by me own?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-directives

I learned vue's **custom directive** today, and start wondering if I can **write a custom directive that has same function as `v-model`**. but I find the difficulty to do the two way binding in the directive's hooks, any help?

Answer (score -1):

Yes,
you should pass `value` props to your component and then `emit` `input` for changing `value`
e.g.:
We have input component:

```
<template>
  <input :value="innerValue" @input="change($event.target.value)">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TextField",
  props: ["value"],
  computed: {
    innerValue() {
      return this.value;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change(e) {
      console.log(e);
      this.$emit("input", e);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

and we use it in parent component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <text-field v-model="value"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TextField from "./components/TextField";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    TextField
  },
  data: () => ({
    value: ""
  })
};
</script>
```